# is it best practice to put List in a log statement

Tags: java, rest, logging

i've an API ..which takes a list of string as input , and returns a list with valid strings based on some filter conditions.
currently i'm logging the whole list as soon as the controller method starts executing.

wanted to check like is it a good practice to print list as the list can be big and it will be printing lots of data in logs

Answer (score 0):

Not a great idea to print long logs in your info level logs. You can set log level as debug for long data logs which will be useful to avoid cluttering your info level logs.